# Run Logback in Debug

Tags: java, logging, logback

I've recently switched from log4j to logback and am wondering if there is an easy way to run logback in debug mode, similar to log4j's `log4j.debug` property. I need to see where it is picking up my `logback.xml` from.

The docs mention using a `StatusPrinter` to print out logback's internal status, but that would require code changes.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

This has been fixed in Logback 1.0.4. You can now use `-Dlogback.debug=true` to enable debugging of the logback setup.

-- Old Answer --

Unfortunately, there is no way to enable debugging via a System property. You have to use `<configuration debug="true">` in the `logback.xml`. Please submit a feature request.

Comment: Feature is "fixed" and is in logback 1.0.4.

Comment: To be absolutely clear, you can now enable Logback debugging with a system property, e.g. `-Dlogback.debug=true`. Via http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2013/07/18/logback-config-showing-debug-level/.

Comment: ...except that it is currently not possible to enable this if you're using Groovy configuration: [setting logback.debug property with groovy config throws exceptions when getting loggers](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1180).

Answer (score 7):

This is how I do it.  I set a system property called 'log.level', then I reference it in logback.xml.

Edit: <s>The downside is that you MUST have 'log.level' always set.  The way I deal with this is to check in my main method and set it to INFO if not already set, be sure to do this before you first logging calls.  Then I can override on the command line, and have a sensible default.</s>

Here is how it looks in my logback.xml:

```xml
<configuration>
    <logger name="com.mycompany.project" level="${log.level}" />
    <logger name="httpclient" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.cfg.annotations" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.quartz" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-16thread] %-5level %-35.35logger{30} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="${log.level:-INFO}">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you can give the property a default value on your logback.xml in case it's not defined, like this: `<root level="${log.level:-info}">` That way you don't need to set it onthe main method if not set.

Comment: Thanks I missed that. Now you mention it I can see it in the docs http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#defaultValuesForVariables

Comment: Thank you for both comments. In Eclipse I can no set an environment variable in the run configuration to turn off logging when running mvn site, but have a default level of debug when running single tests in Eclipse. Thanks.

Comment: If you like my answer, please up vote it. That's how this site works. :-)

Comment: Good answer, I like that most

Answer (score 2):

I could not make it work using the chosen answer. However, the following worked:

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config-debug.xml com.domain.Main
```

Just add a file (`config-debug.xml` in this example) somewhere on your server and leave it there when you need to debug. Like the following.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Run your application using the afore mentioned `-D` parameter.

When things are back to normal, remove the `-D` parameter and restart your application.

Source: [Chapter 3: Logback configuration](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the status listener class via system property:

```
java -Dlogback.statusListenerClass=ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener ...
```

See: [Logback manual](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#logback.statusLC)

Answer (score 1):

Well, It's pretty easy. Either you can use

```
log.level = debug
```

inside the application.properties of Spring boot.

or you can also set this in the configuration file of logback.xml

```
<root level="${log.level}">
    <appender-ref ref="ANY_APPENDER" />
</root>
```

Answer (score -1):

In eclipse you can have multiple run configurations. Open your main class. Go to Debug dropdown on eclipse toolbar and select Debug configurations. Click the New launch configuration icon at the top left. Give your launch configuration a better name. Click the Arguments tab under the name and enter -Dlog.level=debug or whatever you want. Click Close or Debug

You can do this again and specify -Dlog.level=warn for example.