# How to log from within a logback configuration object

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm implementing my own TurboFilter and I'm wondering how to log from within this class.

I can't use the logback's Logger because it calls my turbo filter and so I'll get the java.lang.StackOverflowError. Is there any recommendation how to log inside logback configuration classes?

I notice there are methods 'addInfo, addError, etc.'on the ContextAware interface which every TurboFilter implements, but when I use addError(), nothing appears in my log files neither on the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used is to turn the logback's [debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802054/run-logback-in-debug) on. I can see all those 'addInfo, addError, etc.' then.