# Spring boot logging into multiple files

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, slf4j

Is there any way I can configure spring boot logging to multiple files/console based on the configuration? i.e Some of the log statements should write into an audit file and normal log statements should go to console/normal log file.

Below is the code I have tried on spring boot example application.

logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="file" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hello" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Below is the application.properties entries

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.file=logs/spring-boot-logging.log
```

Below the   HelloController

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloController.class);

    Logger logger1 = LoggerFactory.getLogger("file");

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {

        logger.info("My Log test");
        logger1.info("My Audit test");


        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

Can someone please help? Did anyone face similar situation?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Standard logback example, two files with different packages going to different files :

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>myApp1.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>myApp1.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.package1.foo" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE1" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="com.package2.bar" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE2" />
  </logger>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another logger and appender in your configuration file and create logger object using the name of Logger defined in the configuration. For more explanation
check
[Spring boot multiple log files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39103771/3589749)

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot logging into multiple files and we can create log into selected class also.
I used the following `logback.xml`

```
<configuration>
<appender name="logOutPut" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/WebServe-logback.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/WebServe-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>    
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="errorlab" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/error-logback.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/error-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>    
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="jdbc.sqltiming.appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/WebServe-sql-timing.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">       
        <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/WebServe-sql-timing-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>    
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.tasks.MailNotificationTask">
   <level value="ALL" />
   <appender-ref ref="errorlab" />
</logger>

<logger name="jdbc.sqltiming">
    <appender-ref ref="jdbc.sqltiming.appender" />
</logger>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="logOutPut" />
</root>
```

Dependency :

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```