# Can Spring logging into multiple files by groups?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

According to [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103771/spring-boot-multiple-log-files), I can log my application log to multiple files manually. Can I do it by the group listed in [Spring docs.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-groups)?
Example below:

Tomcat.log

```
2022-05-09 17:13:37.738  INFO 40656 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-05-09 17:13:37.746  INFO 40656 --- [           main] com.example.MyApplication   : Started MyApplication in 7.302 seconds (JVM running for 8.053)
2022-05-09 17:16:03.503  INFO 40656 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-05-09 17:16:03.504  INFO 40656 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-05-09 17:16:03.506  INFO 40656 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
```

Hibernate.log

```
Hibernate: 
SELECT * FROM USER_MASTER;
Hibernate: 
SELECT * FROM USER_CONFIG;
```