# Which configuration file(s) is Logback using?

Tags: logback, slf4j

Is there a system property to make Slf4J and Logback tell which `logback.xml` and `logback-test.xml` files it found and which one it is using? I 'd expect to see that on in the log itself or in `System.out`.

For example, I 've got a Java project that clearly has no `src/main/resources/logback.xml` nor a `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml` file but Logback does seem to find one when I run my unit tests. I do have up to 100 dependencies (none which should include a `logback.xml` in theory) and checking them all one by one is impractical.

Note that I cannot use `<configuration debug="true">` in my configuration file as I don't know where my configuration file is to begin with. I would like the same effect though.

Comment: Try running your app with `-Dlogback.debug=true` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802054/run-logback-in-debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-Dlogback.debug=true` as stated by Tony in the comments.
Then this shows up:

```
15:14:22,155 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
15:14:22,156 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-test.xml] at [file:/.../target/test-classes/logback-test.xml]
15:14:22,333 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
15:14:22,338 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [consoleAppender]
15:14:22,354 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
15:14:22,378 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.optaplanner] to INFO
15:14:22,379 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
15:14:22,379 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [consoleAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
15:14:22,379 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
15:14:22,380 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@1e965684 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

From which specifically this line matters:

```
... - Found resource [logback-test.xml] at [file:/.../target/test-classes/logback-test.xml]
```

If nothing shows up, it's either using the default logging configuration (everything DEBUG) or not recognizing the system property. Good luck figuring out which case it is ([vote for this jira](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1226)).

Comment: Slf4j does not support -Dslf4j.debug yet to figure out which logging implementation is used. [Vote for this jira.](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-381)